# python: groupby - function called when grouping

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, group-by

All I would like to do a groupby and call a function at the same time.

Here is the function

```
def dollar_wtd_two(DF, kw_param, kw_param2):
    return np.sum(DF[kw_param] * DF[kw_param2]) / DF[kw_param2].sum()
```

The function `dollar_wtd_two` has 3 parameters  `DF` (the dataframe) and columns names of the same dataframe `DF`. Conceptually here what I would like to do:

```
DF.groupby(['prime_broker_id', 'country_name'], 
      as_index=False).agg({"notional_current": np.sum, "new_column":dollar_wtd_two(DF, 
           kw_param, kw_param2) })
```

Basically the `groupby` would do simple operations like sum or average and also more involved operations where I would call functions similar to `dollar_wtd_two`

Here is how the output of `DF` would like without the `"new_column"`

```
  DF.groupby(['prime_broker_id', 'country_name'], 
          as_index=False).agg({"notional_current": np.sum })
```

Output 1:

```
   prime_broker_id    country_name  notional_current  
0           BARCAP         AUSTRIA      2.616735e+07       
1           BARCAP         BELGIUM      6.327196e+07       
2           BARCAP         DENMARK      1.286309e+07        
3           BARCAP         FINLAND      4.181843e+07       
4           BARCAP          FRANCE      1.579292e+08      
5           BARCAP         GERMANY      2.653451e+08      
6           BARCAP         IRELAND      1.037968e+07
```

I am not able to show the output of `DF` with `"new_column":dollar_wtd_two(DF, kw_param, kw_param2)`. However individually the output of  `dollar_wtd_two(DF, kw_param, kw_param2)`  should look like this:

Output 2:

```
prime_broker_id  country_name  
BARCAP           AUSTRIA            25.009402
                 BELGIUM            25.083404
                 DENMARK            25.000000
                 FINLAND            25.034493
                 FRANCE             25.000000
                 GERMANY            25.007943
                 IRELAND            25.000000
                 ISRAEL            399.242997
```

The idea is to combine Output 1 and Output 2 in one operation. Please let me if it is unclear.

Any help is more than welcome

Thanks a lot

Comment: Is possible create [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ?

Comment: i have added examples. Hopefully that helps?

Comment: Hmm, is possible run yourcode for excepted output?

Comment: not sure i understand. You would like to see the error message?

Comment: no, maybe I am not explain good. I think the best is create some small data sample like `df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': ['a','a','a','a','b','b','b','c','d'],
    'B': list(range(9))
})
print (df)` and then add expected output with this sample data. Because problem of your question is I cannot run your functions

Comment: Hello Jezrael,  I partly found the answer to my problem.  `DF.groupby(['prime_broker_id', 'country_name'], as_index=False).apply( lambda DF, a ,b: sum(DF[a] * DF[b]), 'kw_param', 'param2')`